# Next.js version 13.4.4 not working on server start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js.

I have installed **Next.js version 13.4.4** in my machine but when I run my server using `npm run dev` command, it's always giving me same error which is `Failed to compile ./app/globals.css Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) > @tailwind base; | @tailwind components;| @tailwind utilities;`

I tried installing tailwind css, clear npm cache but still same issue. However, there is one question is being asked by terminal i.e., `Would you like to customize the default import alias? » No / Yes` either I check yes or no, it still giving me same error every time.

Comment: have you created tailwind.config.js file. If yes, can you provide tailwind.config.js and global.css content

Comment: tailwind.config.js =>

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: do you have postcss.config.js

Comment: postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

Unable to post global.css

Comment: seems ok, try installing package again 
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

Comment: import global.css in app.tsx
import '@/styles/globals.css'

Comment: there is no app.tsx as I selected no for typescript and not even app.js. However, there is layout.js in app folder which already having path of global.css. In global.css file it is not able to recognise @tailwind, although I installed it again along with postcss and autoprefixer as requested by you. Still not works :(

Comment: if you have used js, then you should have _app.js file. Because it is the main file or base file for next.js. My last options would be  re-initializing project again and begin again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253892/discussion-between-anand-deep-singh-and-codewithsg).